# Enumerate JSON master detail arrays

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a view model that contains 2 related (master / detail) arrays that I want to bind to.

```
  var ViewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.CategoryList = ko.observableArray(data.CategoryList);
        self.ItemList = ko.observableArray(data.ItemList);
   }
```

Where Category is an array of `{ categoryID: 1, name: "Red Items" }` etc

and Item is an array of `{ itemID: 1, categoryID: 1, name: "Red Widget" }` etc

I have a handful of categories and possibly several hundred items. I am struggling with how to represent these in my view model in a way that I can enumerate categories and get to associated items or across all items and get to categories.

It doesn't seem efficient to maintain duplicate information on both lists and I don't want to be sending more data than needed over the wire.

One approach: create Item and Category objects and modify the prototype to include filtering (ko.computed) functions. `category.Items()` or `item.Category().Name` but I am not 100% how to best accomplish this within knockout.js given my need to load and save data.

I am not wed to arrays of simple JSON objects. Assuming I go the function / prototype route, how do I load and save my arrays of objects?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you require a better data structure than an array, since -as you said- it's not optimal to keep duplicate information. Instead of having an array listing your categories, why don't use a hash table, or as we simply know in javascript, an object?

```
{
    1: "Red Items",
    2: "Blue Items",
    3: "Green Items",
    4: "Yellow Items",
}
```

(You can use a simple method to create the hash from the array)

```
var createHashFromArray = function(arr) {
  var hash = {}
  for (var i = 0, var len = arr.length; i < len; i++)
    hash[i] = arr[i];
  return hash;
}
```

From there, you can bind your viewModel according to the categories you need. You can even set up them as dynamic arrays using `ko.computed` in order to organize them in your view.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: redItemsOnly">
  <span data-bind="text: itemId">ID</span>
  <span data-bind="text: name">NAME</span>
</div>
```

And in your javascript...

```
self.redItemsOnly = ko.computed(function() {
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.ItemList(), function(item) 
{
    return self.CategoryHash[item.categoryID] === "Red Items"
});
}, self)
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I hope this approach helps you to find other ways to come up with what you need.